# Require a CSS file in an HTML file without using webpack

Tags: html, css, node.js, electron

I am working on an Electron project and using Electron-packager to package my app.

However, with my current folder structure, all CSS files located in the parent folder of my Electron project/package.json are not being copied to the packaged application.

This is my structure:

```
- GUI
--- CSS
- Apps
---Demo
------package.json, etc
---Demo2
------package.json, etc
---Demo3
------package.json, etc
```

I build apps while inside `Demox` folder.  Problem is I can't move `GUI` folder to inside Demo/Demo2/Demo3 since it will contain just the same files and it would be redundant.

However, `electron-packager` does not support packaging of files from outside the actual Demox folder.

It was suggested that I move these CSS files to `node_modules` instead.

But how do I `require` these CSS files from the node_modules folder to an html file?  Is there any other way WITHOUT using `webpack`?  I'm hoping to keep this simple and stay away from setting webpack up unless I have no other choice.

For reference, here is the question I posted on the Electron-packager github:
https://github.com/electron/electron-packager/issues/1089

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Was able to come up with a solution now.

Since I have moved `node_modules` folder to the very root (`C:\node_modules`, so it can be used by all node projects residing in C: drive), I just used an absolute path and link from there:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/sample-css/button.css">`

Works well for my needs.

Thanks everyone.